# IllegalStateException : Gremlin Server must be configured to use the JanusGraphManager

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

```
Set<String> graphNames = JanusGraphFactory.getGraphNames();
for(String name:graphNames) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

The above snippet produces the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gremlin Server must be configured to use the JanusGraphManager.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.getGraphNames(JanusGraphFactory.java:175)
    at com.JanusTest.controllers.JanusController.getPersonDetail(JanusController.java:66)
```

my.properties

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

gremlin-server.yaml

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphManager: org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
graphs: {
  ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/my.properties,
}
plugins:
  - janusgraph.imports
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistryV1d0] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536

maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer to this is similar to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622803/5025129).

The call to `JanusGraphFactory.getGraphNames()` needs to be sent to the remote server. If you're working in the Gremlin Console, first establish a remote sessioned connection then set remote console mode.

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182

gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [localhost:8182]-[5206cdde-b231-41fa-9e6c-69feac0fe2b2] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
```

Then as described in the JanusGraph docs for "[Listing the Graphs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/configuredgraphfactory.html#listing-the-graphs)":

> `ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames()` will return a set of graph names for which you have created configurations using the ConfigurationManagementGraph APIs.
>
> `JanusGraphFactory.getGraphNames()` on the other hand returns a set of graph names for which you have instantiated and the references are stored inside the JanusGraphManager.

If you are not using the Gremlin Console, then you should be using a remote client, such as the TinkerPop [`gremlin-driver`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.9/reference/#connecting-via-java) (Java), to send your requests to the Gremlin Server.